# PHP- trim() function not working

Tags: php, trim

I have problem when used function `trim()` with this code

```
$handle = @fopen("55.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {      
        $d = explode(" ", $buffer);
        foreach($d as $val) { 
            echo '<br>'.trim($val,'.');  //why not work 
        }   
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }   
    fclose($handle);
}
```

The `trim()` doesn't trim `'.'`.

Comment: Well, what is the input data?  Does it have trailing whitespace after the trailing `.` that you're trying to `trim()`?  Show the sample contents of `55.txt`

Comment: The example you regrade will remove "." from the beginning and end of the contents of 55.txt

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way.  Don't worry - we almost always ask for more information and your first question at least is concise and includes code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Additional to the lines themselves, the `fgets()` function returns the line breaks from the file, which are after the dots in the string, thus preventing the dots from being trimmed, because they are not actually the last character.

Try to trim the dots and possible line breaks at the same time:

```
echo '<br>'.trim($val, ".\r\n");
```

Comment: thank you ,but why add \r\n can you Lead me to site or book to learn who I do that.

Comment: These are the line break characters in a PHP string,  here's a little more about these http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=8021

Answer (score 0):

do

```
substr(trim($val),1,stlen(trim($val)));
```

instead of

```
trim($val,'.');
```

if you want to remove  the leading and trailing `'.'`

Comment: Um,  I believe the OP wants to _remove_ the leading and trailing `.`, not add them.

Comment: @user201635 is this what you are looking for?